# A non-trival open polynomial function must be surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a nonconstant polynomial function.

If $f$ is an open mapping, then $f$ must be a surjection?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think so.  If f isn't surjective then Image(f) will be bounded above or below [I think that's easy to show as a polynomial is continuous] and have a max or min (i.e. the sup Image(f) is in Image(f); I think that is easy to show.)  The max and min will not be an interior point of Image(f) so Image(f) isn't open, so it isn't an open mapping.  I *think*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y)=x^2+(xy-1)^2$.  Then $f$ is always positive, so it is not surjective; I claim $f$ is open.  Indeed, it is easy to check using calculus that $f$ has no local minima or maxima, so $f$ is open by [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1471489/86856).