# Is there a polynomial accepting all positive and only positive values?

Tags: polynomials

Please help to prove that there is no polynomial
$p\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to (0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What do you mean by a polynomial on $R^n$?

Comment: What about $p(x) = 1 + \sum_j x_j^2$?

Comment: @asahay That does not produce any values in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Théophile you're assuming OP means that $image(p)=(0,\infty)$ rather than $image(p) \subseteq (0,\infty)$ ?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes, I assume that "all positive and only positive values" means that the image is $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279497/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2481978/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493380/42969

Answer (score 3):

Although it may be counterintuitive, yes, there is; for example,
$$f(x,y) = (1-xy)^2+x^2,$$
which I found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3822, which in turn comes from [a comment in math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/30979#30979).

You can see that $f(x,y)>0$ everywhere, and we cannot have $f(x,y)=0$. On the other hand, for any $\epsilon > 0$, you can find $x,y$ such that $f(x,y) = \epsilon$. (Specifically, $f(\sqrt{\epsilon}, \frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon}}) = \epsilon$.)

Comment: why would it be counterintuitive?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon It is not true for a polynomial in one variable, for example, so it's a good demonstration that adding a dimension can have interesting results.

Comment: oh wow that was mindblowing. thanks for the info. is this some commonly known elementary result in analysis? or algebra? or even just calculus or something?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I'm surprised too! You'll find it on this list of [common false beliefs in mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/30979#30979). I think it also comes down to the way we learn calculus, where polynomials are the "well-behaved" functions. There are any number of exercises like "find the global extrema of this polynomial", and it easily becomes an instinct that they must exist if it's bounded.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon A polynomial is continuous,the set of values it takes is connected. A non-constant polynomial $f$ of one variable must have $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}|f(x)|=\infty$. If $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ then $f$ takes all real values (and the set $(-\infty,\infty)$ of values is closed). Now assume $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$. There are $a,b$ with $f(x)>f(0)$ if $x<a$ or $x>b$. Then $f$ achieves its minimum $m$ on the closed interval $[a,b]$, $m$ also global (absolute) minimum. The set of values of $f$ is $[m,\infty)$,closed.

Comment: @Mirko right thanks for the info!